# How to use bash script? Input vs output

Tags: bash

I use bash script in which I modified definition of input and output:

```
###Original definition input vs. output:
    infile=$1
    outfile="${infile}.mlf"
    tmpfile="${infile}.tmp"
    tmpfile1="${infile}.tmp1"
```

for use in different folders, so script, input and output are in different folder:

```
###Modified definition input vs. output:
        mid=$1
        infile="/var/www/tmp/input/$mid.vtt"
        outfile="/var/www/tmp/output/$mid.mlf"
        tmpfile="{infile}.tmp"
        tmpfile1="${infile}.tmp1"
```

I  want to run this script. It will be used to convert text files "$mid.vtt" (mid means multimedia id) from "input" folder to "$mid.mlf" to "output" folder. I modified as it is shown, but  some error messages are shown:

> "cat: /var/www/tmp/output/1.vtt.vtt: No such file or directory" 
>   "cat: /var/www/tmp/output/1.vtt.vtt.tmp1: No such file or directory" 
>   "rm: cannot remove `/var/www/tmp/output/1.vtt.vtt.tmp1': No such file or directory"

The whole bash script is below. I changed only definition of input vs. outputs.

```
###input vs. output
                mid=$1
                infile="/var/www/tmp/input/$mid.vtt"
                outfile="/var/www/tmp/output/$mid.mlf"
                tmpfile="${infile}.tmp"
                tmpfile1="${infile}.tmp1"
                i=1
                touch $tmpfile

            ###script
                cat $infile | grep -v 'WEBVTT' | grep -v "\--" | grep -v '^$' | sed 's/?/./g' | sed 's/!/./g' | tr -d '.' | tr -d "," | tr -d ";" | tr -d ":" | awk '{ print tolower($0) }' > $tmpfile

                nlines=$(cat $tmpfile | wc -l)

                while [ $i -le $nlines ]
                do
                    line=$(cat $tmpfile | sed $i'q;d')
                    printf '%s\n' $line | sed '/^\s*$/d' >> $tmpfile1
                    i=$[$i+1]
                done

            ###export to output
                echo "#!MLF!#" > $outfile
                echo "\"*/dummyfile.lab\"" >> $outfile
                cat $tmpfile1 | awk '{if($0 !~ /\*/) print "0 0 "$0; else print $0}' >> $outfile
                echo "." >> $outfile

            ###deleting tmp files
                rm $tmpfile
                rm $tmpfile1
```

I dont'know where is a problem. I used chmod to set right permissions. Input file exists, folders exist..

Comment: **some error messages are shown** - please edit the question and include them

Comment: You have a typo ( missing a $ sign) in your assignment `tmpfile="{infile}.tmp"` should be `tmpfile="${infile}.tmp"` .

Comment: I'm going to guess that either (or both) of the input and output directories don't exist but without the exact errors you are seeing that can't possibly be more than a guess.

Comment: Error messages which are shown: "cat: /var/www/tmp/output/1.vtt.vtt: No such file or directory"
"cat: /var/www/tmp/output/1.vtt.vtt.tmp1: No such file or directory"
"rm: cannot remove `/var/www/tmp/output/1.vtt.vtt.tmp1': No such file or directory"

Comment: Looks like you are missing a dollar sign so you end up with a literal `1` instead of `$1`.

Comment: Counting the number of lines so you can loop over line numbers is a massive antipattern.  Just read the file a line at a time.

Comment: A good StackOverflow question should have a single, isolated problem -- with everything unrelated to that problem removed -- as per http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve; as it is, there's a great many problems squashed into a single question.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ACyrxjV0 attempts to refactor the script to avoid some of the abject horrors but I am not at all sure if it is correct.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for you idea, but your code doesn't work even in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Now it works fine.

> mid=$1 infile="/home/var/www/vids/$mid/$mid.vtt"
>   outfile="/var/www/tmp/vtt-to-mlf/${mid}.mlf"
>   tmpfile="/var/www/tmp/vtt-to-mlf/${mid}.tmp"
>   tmpfile1="/var/www/tmp/vtt-to-mlf/${mid}.tmp1"